# Pikaday selecting 2018 even though the yearRange set is [1968, 2005]

Tags: javascript, pikaday

How to make 2005 be selected as default year in the select box.

```js
$(function () {
    var field = $('#calendar')[0];
    

    var pika = new Pikaday({
        field: field,
        yearRange: [1968, 2005],
        onSelect: function () {
            console.log('selected');
        },
        onOpen: function () {
            console.log('open');
        },

        onClose: function () {
            console.log('closed');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>2018 year is selcted even though year range is [1968, 2005]</h1>
<input id="calendar" type="text" value=""></input>
```

Comment: defaultDate the initial date to view when first opened. It says so on the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use defaultDate like shown on the snippet.
defaultDate will set the calender to given date.
setDefaultDate will choose and highlight the given date.

```js
$(function () {
    var field = $('#calendar')[0];
    var date = new Date(2005,0,1);

    var pika = new Pikaday({
        field: field,
        defaultDate:date,
        setDefaultDate: date,
        yearRange: [1968, 2005],
        onSelect: function () {
            console.log('selected');
        },
        onOpen: function () {
            console.log('open');
        },

        onClose: function () {
            console.log('closed');
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/dbushell/Pikaday/master/pikaday.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>2018 year is selcted even though year range is [1968, 2005]</h1>
<input id="calendar" type="text" value=""></input>
```

Comment: How do i highlight the current date for 2005 ? For example today is 27 june , i want to highlight 27 June of 2005 when the picker is opened, it should always highlight the latest date

Comment: I updated the snippet for you. It will be highlighted when you use setDefaultDate

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it on 2005 on opening:

```
onOpen: function () {
    this.gotoYear(2005);
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms97uved/